# How to unit test code in the repository pattern?

Tags: entity-framework, unit-testing, tdd

How to test this scenario:

> I have a user repository that (so far) only has one method: **SaveUser**.
>   "SaveUser" is suposed to receive a user as a parameter and save it to the DB using EF 6.
>   If the user is new (new user is defined by a "Email" that is not present in the database) the method is supposed to insert it, if its not, the method is supposed to only update it.
>   Technically if this method is called, all business validation are OK, only remaining the act of actually persisting the user

My problem here is: I don't actually want to create a new user or update one every time... this would lead to undesired side effects in the future (let's call it "paper trail")... How do i do it?

Here is the test code:

```
public void CreateOrUpdateUserTest1()
    {
        UserDTO dto = new UserDTO();
        dto.UniqueId = new Guid("76BCB16B-4AD6-416B-BEF6-388D56217E76");
        dto.Name = "CreateOrUpdateUserTest1";
        dto.Email = "leo@leo.com";
        dto.Created = DateTime.Now;
        GeneralRepository repository = new GeneralRepository();
        //Now the user should be CREATED on the DB
        repository.SaveUser(dto);

        dto.Name = "CreateOrUpdateUserTest";
        //Now the user should be UPDATED on the DB
        repository.SaveUser(dto);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repository probably needs to invoke some methods of a third party library to actually persist the data. Unit-testing in such case could only make sense if you could mock the third party library and verify and the particular persistence methods are being correctly invoked by your repository. To achieve this, you need to refactor your code.

Otherwise, you can't unit-test this class, but also consider that maybe there is no need to. The third party library responsible for persistence is a different component, so testing if DB storage works correctly with your classes is rather a matter of [Integration testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_testing).

Comment: tks for the quick reply. I considered your position before, and I insist on this as a unit test because my 3rd part lib might have its behavior changed! that would cause my "GeneralRepository"to fail... wouldnt you aggre? as i said im new at this, pls correct me if i'm wrong!

Comment: @Leonardo I'm not saying that unit-testing here is wrong. I just wouldn't do it - if 3rd party library will change its behaviour your integration tests will detect it. Note also, that unit tests of `GeneralRepository` will not guard against changes in 3rd party library, because these tests (by definition) will test only `GeneralRepository`. That's why Integration Tests exist.

Comment: @Leonardo If you want to unit-test `GeneralRepository` then you'll need to refactor it - allow it to retrieve persistence layer object in constructor. So in your unit-tests you can provide it with a mocked object, and verify its method calls.